# Live data is not getting updated if pass same data

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a live data like this

```
companion object {
    val themUpdateSubscriber = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
}
```

I have subscribe to it like this

```
BaseViewModel.themUpdateSubscriber.observe(this, {
   Log.d(TAG, "Them changed")         
})
```

I am updating live data like this:

```
BaseViewModel.themUpdateSubscriber.value = true
```

The problem is, I am not getting update inside observer if I pass true value and value was already true. This is only happening in some phones.

If anybody can explain why this is working in some phones and why not in other phones then it would be a helpful.

Comment: From which thread are you calling `BaseViewModel.themUpdateSubscriber.value = true`?

Comment: What's the "this" LifecycleOwner?

Comment: Main thread @rajan.kali

Comment: this = activity @NicolaGallazzi

Comment: So the receiver and sender code are in same Activity ?

Comment: no, @rajan.kali

Comment: Then at any given time only one active will be in active state, unless there is multi window or pip, so even if you post the data , it won't be receiving in inactive activity

Comment: its livedata and it will listen to changes and also its aware of activity lifecycle so even if activity is not on screen it will listen to changes @rajan.kali